# When do $n$ vectors add up to give a resultant of zero?

Tags: vectors

> When do $n$ vectors add up to give a resultant of zero?

My take on this questions was this :

So I took up few pencils for the $n=4$,also $n=3$ it has to lie on a plane, whereas two they should be opposite, so coming back, with the $n=4$ I observed that if they formed a closed loop of segments, they would be zero. But the polygon law of addition, had stated that would be the the case only when they are coplanar, but the pencils I arranged up were not coplanar.

P.S. I am honestly sorry if this is not phrased properly, this is my first question, Kindly excuse me.

Comment: Welcome to the site! A few things may help here: can you write out the question in mathematical notation and include some more details? E.g. are the vectors elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$, etc...?

Comment: I do not fully understand the question... but you may be reaching for the concept of linear dependence / linear independence.  Learning how to recognize when a collection of vectors are dependent/independent is an important skill taught early on in a course on Linear Algebra.

Comment: You mention "pencils" and "closed loops", so I assume you are imagining a scenario where you are representing certain vectors each by a pencil pointed in a certain direction and rather than each vector starting from the origin you have your pencils starting from the end of the previous pencil (e.g. arranged eraser to tip) except the first which starts from the origin.  Sure... that is all fine and dandy.  Now, if the final pencil points back to the origin then of course the vectors they represent all sum to zero.

Comment: Now... I have no idea what this "polygon law of addition" is... but maybe its something like "If you have $n$ vectors who add together to zero in $\Bbb R^n$, then they must necessarily all lie in some $(n-1)$ or less dimensional hyper plane."  In the case of $\Bbb R^3$, our usual three-dimensional space, if you have three vectors all adding to zero... then they must be coplanar or colinear, etc...  However, talking about $4$ or more in $\Bbb R^3$ doesn't apply.  You can absolutely have four vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ who add to zero who aren't coplanar, eg $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(-1,-1,-1)$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes , that was correct , i was taking pencils as vectors (head- tail being tip-eraser) , yes , exactly closed loop .

Comment: @JMoravitz In the second one , actually what , Polygon law of vector addition ,according to my textbook is , that if a number of vectors can be represented in magnitude and direction by the sides of a polygon taken in the same order,(all of them head to tail)  then their resultant is represented in magnitude and direction by the closing side of the polygon taken in the opposite order.

Comment: @JMoravitz but  my doubt is , why a polygon (planar , they are assuming coplanar) why not just , say some vectors kept in order in 3D space , and the resultant of these will be the vector from the tail of first vector to head of last vector

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what was written.  The book wrote **if** yada yada is true then this other is true.  The book did not write "**only if**" or "**if and only if**".  You can absolutely have the scenario you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you are confortable with a matrix notation. Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be your $k$-dimensional vectors. We want to sum then and get zero, then we want to know numbers $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n$ such that
$$ \alpha_1 x_1 + \cdots + \alpha_nx_n = 0. $$

Writing $M = \left[\begin{array}{c:c:c:c}x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \end{array}\right]$ a matrix with $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ as columns we can rewrite your equation as the system
$$ M\alpha = 0 $$
where $\alpha = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\ \alpha_2 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n\end{bmatrix}$. Now we need to know how many solutions we have for $M\alpha = 0$. You can find the path to answer that at any Linear Algebra book or course. But here is the answer:

If $k < n$ then you have infinitely many ways to do that.

If $k = n$ and $M$ has non-zero determinant then the only way is to set $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n = 0$.

If $k=n$ and $M$ has zero determinant, then you have infinitely many ways to do that.

If $k > n$ and you can find other $n-k$ vectors $x_{k+1}, \cdots, x_{n}$ such that $M$ has non-zero determinant then the only way is to set $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n = 0$.

If $k > n$ and you can't find other $n-k$ vectors $x_{k+1}, \cdots, x_{n}$ such that $M$ has non-zero determinant then you have infinitely many ways to do that.

Comment: But a small doubt , so we have taken n vectors that add up to zero , then why are we scaling them using matrix alpha ?